# Different result while reading the FormsAuthenticationTicket

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, formsauthentication, formsauthenticationticket

I have a two blocks of codes which are supposed to do the same job, that is copying the whole `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and changing one bit of it which is stored in `UserData`.

The first code reads correctly everything including `UserData`. The second does not include `UserData`. It simply returns an empty string. I realised that when an exception was thrown because if an empty object.

Any idea?

The first code:

```
string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket oldTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    UserData userDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(oldTicket.UserData);
    userDataObj.PassChangeRequired = user.PasswordChangeRequired;
    string userdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDataObj);
    FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                                oldTicket.Version,
                                                oldTicket.Name,
                                                oldTicket.IssueDate,
                                                oldTicket.Expiration,
                                                oldTicket.IsPersistent,
                                                userdata,
                                                oldTicket.CookiePath);
    authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
    Response.Cookies.Set(authCookie);
}
```

The second code:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket oldTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    UserData userDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(oldTicket.UserData);
    userDataObj.PassChangeRequired = user.PasswordChangeRequired;
    string userdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userDataObj);
    FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                                                oldTicket.Version,
                                                oldTicket.Name,
                                                oldTicket.IssueDate,
                                                oldTicket.Expiration,
                                                oldTicket.IsPersistent,
                                                userdata,
                                                oldTicket.CookiePath);
    authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
    Response.Cookies.Set(authCookie);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [MSDN for the GetAuthCookie()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getauthcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that you use in example 2, you will see that it says:

> Creates an authentication cookie for a given user name.

What this means is that when you make this call in example 2, you are actually getting back a brand new authentication cookie that was just created and not the one that you have already set.  This is why the `UserData` property is empty/null.